# How to load only the most recent file from a directory where the filenames startswith the date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, glob

I have files in one directory/folder named:

1. `2022-07-31_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv`
2. `2022-08-31_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv`
3. `2022-09-30_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv`

The folder will be updated with each month's file in the same format as above eg.:

- `2022-10-31_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv`
- `2022-11-30_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv`

I want to only load the most recent month's .csv into a pandas dataframe, not all the files. How can I do this (maybe using glob)?

I have seen this used for prefixes using:

```
dir_files = r'/path/to/folder/*'

dico={}

for file in Path(dir_files).glob('DATA_GVAX_COMBINED_*.csv'):
    dico[file.stem.split('_')[-1]] = file

max_date = max(dico)
```

Comment: With that file naming convention you only need a list of all files in the directory which you can then naturally sort. Are there any other files in the directory apart from ones with this naming structure?

Comment: yes there will be other with different naming conventions @Cobra

Answer (score 0):

Glob the directory with the pattern for known files of interest. Sort (natural) on the basename.

```
from glob import glob as GLOB
from os.path import join as JOIN, basename as BASENAME

def get_latest(directory):
    if all_files := list(GLOB(JOIN(directory, '*_DATA_GVAX_ARPA_COMBINED.csv'))):
        return sorted(all_files, key=BASENAME)[-1]

print(get_latest('/Users/Cobra'))
```